# javascript getting rid array reference

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, reference

This is a react minesweeper and it involves setState when the user wants to choose a new grid size. When the user clicks the grid should be recreated, but there are some reference problems thanks to the prev state.

When I first `console.log(array);` it is not empty thanks to the prev state. When I `console.log(array[m][n]['value'])` it says all the values are 0, but when I `console.log(array);` right after it the array contains `'b'` values which are set from the `addBombs`method which is invoked after the `createMap`.

What should I do?

```
createMap (sizeX, sizeY, bombNumber) {
  let array = [];
  while (array.length > 0) {
    array.pop();
  }
  array.length = 0;
  console.log(array); // not totally empty, but it says length 0.

  for (var m = 0; m < sizeY; m++) {
    array[m] = new Array();
    for (var n = 0; n < sizeX; n++) {
      array[m][n] = { value: 0, state: 'closed' };
      console.log(array[m][n]['value']); // Prints 0 for all of them.
    }
  }
  console.log(array); // There are 'b' values in the array.
  return array.slice();
}

createTable(props) {
  const sizeX = props.sizeX;
  const sizeY = props.sizeY;
  const bombNumber = props.bombNumber;

  const map = this.createMap(sizeX, sizeY, bombNumber);
  const newMap = map.slice();
  const newestMap = this.addBombs(newMap, sizeX, sizeY, bombNumber);
  const newestestMap = newestMap.slice();
  const mMap = this.calculateFieldValues(newestestMap);
  const nMap = mMap.slice();
  return nMap;
}

addBombs (map, sizeX, sizeY, bombNumber) {
  let bombFields = [];

  while (bombFields.length < bombNumber) {
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (sizeY * sizeX - 1))
    if (!bombFields.includes(randomNumber)) {
      bombFields.push(randomNumber);
    }
  }

  bombFields.forEach((number) => {
    const i = Math.floor(number / sizeX);
    let j = (number % sizeX);
    if (j === -1) {
      j = sizeX - 1;
    }
    map[i][j]['value'] = 'b';
  });

  return map;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can't replicate this - can you show your addBombs code?

Comment: Same here, I can't find any 'b' values in the array at the end of the createMap functions.

Comment: I guess you need some screwed up setState to have this issue.

Comment: I guess so, because in plain old JavaScript, your code is working as intended.